# C#: Get index of Table after specific paragraph

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, office-2007

Assume I have the following structure:-

[image]

I wanna get the index of second table after "1.3    The headline of paragraph3", means the next:-

The input is

> 1.3   The headline of paragraph3

The expected output

> 4

this is the  forth table in the document, or you can say

`The requested member of the collection` equlas four.

The target of this for using the next code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Documents docs = app.Documents;
Document doc = docs.Open(sDocPath, ReadOnly: true);
Table t = doc.Tables[4] // 4 that what I need
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the code below in VB.NET, or simply convert it to C#.

```
  <TestMethod()> Public Sub getDocText()
  Dim filepath As String = "C:\Test Table.docx"
  If File.Exists(filepath) AndAlso (Path.GetExtension(filepath).ToUpper.Equals(".DOCX") Or Path.GetExtension(filepath).ToUpper.Equals(".DOC")) Then
     Dim app As Word.Application = New Word.Application
     Dim doc As Word.Document = app.Documents.Open(filepath)
     Dim topic1Range As Word.Range = doc.Content
     Dim topic2Range As Word.Range = doc.Content
     Dim Find As Word.Find = topic1Range.Find()
     Find.Execute("1.2 The headline of paragraph3")

     Dim Find2 As Word.Find = topic2Range.Find()
     Find2.Execute("1.3 The headline of paragraph3")

     Dim contentRange As Word.Range = doc.Range(topic1Range.End, topic2Range.Start)
     MsgBox(contentRange.Tables.Count)
     app.Quit()
  End If
End Sub
```